# Managing screen flow

Tags: android

To keep it simple I have 3 screens. A, B and C.
You can access Screen B or C from screen A.
You can access Screen C from screen B
You can access Screen B from screen C

Data from screen A is passed to B and C

What I am looking to do is create a button on screen B and C and where ever they are takes it back to screen A. I do not want to start a new activity of A as it requires the data it created

Also is there a way to overrule what the back button on the phone does. ie if on screen C it goes back to A even is the user clicked B and then C?

Thanks for your time

Comment: What do you need.Overriding back button so that you can call the activity you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suggestion is to work with results and [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29).

If you are at C from B and you click on button to go to A you can set the result intent;

```
Intent result = new Intent();
result.putExtra("gotoA", true);
setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
finish();
```

Then catch that result in B by overriding [onActivityResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29), and checking the intent extra, then finish B.

Comment: Not 100% sure clear on this. You add that code the screen C or A on the startActivityforresult()?

Comment: you start C from B with startActivityForResult(), set the result (code shown) at C on buttonA press, then override onActivityResult() in B to handle the result, and when the resultdata has gotoA to true (which is just a flag i made up), you can call finish() there and it will go to back to A. 
The activities are managed by a stack, so its FIFO.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the back button by re-implementing `onBackPressed`

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    // Close B
    // Close C
}
```

For passing data from one Activity to another, you can use `Intent.putExtra()` (to send from A to B,C) and use `onActivityResult()` + `setResult()` for communicating it back to A.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can override what the back button does (it is not a good practice though). You will need to override the `onBackPressed()` method in ActivityC and inside this method

```
    Intent homeIntent=new Intent(this,ActivityA.class);
    homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(homeIntent);
```

Edit: see the docs for [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) it will create your Activity just if it doesn't exist, and will clear all the Activities on top of it. You could also pass data on this intent for the ActivityA.

Comment: Would this overwrite the Arraylist of data that was passed from A or do I need to pass the Arraylist back to A when I do this?

Comment: Your question confuses me...I'm not sure what you are doing but I don't think that you need to pass the ArrayList back.